# MAUI Blazor not respecting device language on iOS

Tags: ios, maui, maui-blazor

If I create a new MAUI Blazor application and adding two inputs like:

```
<input type="date" title="Date"/>
<input type="time" title="Time" >
```

It mixes Swedish (my preferred language) and English.
[image: Mixes Swedish and English]

[image: Time as well]

Has anyone else solved this problem?
Repro:https://github.com/vallgrenerik/MauiApp2_Input_Time_Date.App

Comment: Could be a bug. You may want to report that to the official GitHub repo: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues

Comment: Yeah, done that  https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15364

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No bug/issue.
As Gerald mentioned in https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15364, we have to set the `CFBundleLocalizations` in the info.plist file.
Following code will show Swdish.

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>sv</string>
</array>
```

[image]